# Missing Ship / Passenger record?

Tags: immigration, ship

In the naturalization certificate of Leon(indas) Zoto, it is written that he arrived on April 22, 1911 in New York on the Calabria Ship. See [here](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:33S7-958X-322J?i=250&cc=1913395&personaUrl=%2Fark%3A%2F61903%2F1%3A1%3AQGB1-2PL2).

However, there is no sign of him on ancestry.com or familysearch in 1911.
Could anyone help me locate the arrival record of the ship or of the person?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manifest got his names switched. (That is, the clerk wrote *Leonidas* in the "Family Name" column and *V. Zotos* in the "Given Name" column.)

Index: https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:JJK1-6M5
Image: https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3Q9M-C9TQ-X92M?i=745&cc=1368704 (Roll 1665, vol 3673-3675, 21 Apr 1911, image 746 of 1291)
Statue of Liberty -- Ellis Island Foundation passenger ID 101113070299, frame 543, line 3

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have thought of permuting the names...

Comment: Would you by any chance be luckier than me in finding Gregor(ios) Lakuriqi's first date of arrival (ca. 1911). Here is his WWI registration card (1917) : https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:K6K3-QXZH
Here is arrival information in 1920 : https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:J68C-5NT

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere with Gregorios. I'll try again later, but in the meantime, you know about Steve Morse's search forms (https://stevemorse.org/ellis2/ellisgold.html), right?

Comment: Can we incorporate this into the question and answers, please?  Remember, the goal here is to write up our problems so other people can use them as examples to solve their own cases.  Both of these are about finding the arrival record, so it's fine to put both of them into the same question -- you can have Example 1, Example 2 & the answers can refer to whichever example it is.

Comment: @JPmiaou, I do.

Comment: @JanMurphy, if someone finds something for Gregorios, then we can certainly add him to the question and answer, but as things currently stand, there's no point.